# PHP-MySQL: Check if column value increased then

Tags: php, mysql

once again I need help from greater minds than mine.

I don't know if this even is possible, but I'd really like if it were.

I have a MySQL database with table named `character_data` and in that table are the following columns:

- `PlayerUID`- Unique key for each player
- `KillsH`- How many player kills does this player have
- `Lat`- Position coordinate latitude
- `Lon`- Position coordinate longitude

Game itself has "Circular PVP Zones" Now what I want is that when player kills another player within that zone then killers score increases, but if killer was not in the zone then his score decreases. Since I'm trying to create a stats page for the website I need a script that checks if value in `KillsH` has increased and then do next lines.

So the logical explanation should be like that:

1. Check if KillsH increased by 1
2. If true then get player coordinates (Lat and Lon)
3. Check if coordinates are in range of previously defined coordinates.
4. If true then player score +20 else -20.

Main issue is that I don't know how to make a script to check if database is changed. Other points in the list I could probably manage.
How could I archive that? Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So find a procedure in which `KillsH` increased and add your logics there.

Comment: I've been looking a full day for a solution, since I havent found one yet, that's why I posted here.